# Scope of [heterocyclic-compounds] and [aromatic-compounds]

Tags: discussion, tags

Edit: Following a suggestion by Mithoron I've renamed it to [heterocyclic-compounds](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heterocyclic-compounds) which is also more in line with the tags that we currently have.

---

Edit 2: I've also done up a [tag wiki](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tags/heterocyclic-compounds/info). Feel free to edit/criticise/comment/praise/worship.

---

I'll keep this short and sweet, since I've gotta head off in 10 minutes. The tag [heterocyclic-chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heterocyclic-chemistry) seems to have popped up recently. I think that this is a good tag to have, there are numerous books written on the topic and I had an entire course on it. There are already plenty of suitable questions.

As far as I know, "heterocyclic" includes saturated and unsaturated rings, therefore chemistry involving piperidine, pyrrolidine, tetrahydrofuran, etc. would come under this tag. So would chemistry about pyrrole and pyridine.

<s>I've personally decided that questions about pyrrole, pyridine, etc. should also be tagged with [aromatic-compounds](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aromatic-compounds), since these are aromatic heterocycles. I don't really anticipate any objections, but if there anybody disagrees, please do drop an answer. I'm writing this to make sure that everything is transparent and that there's a record of this discussion.</s>

Note that the previous paragraph is superseded by the following discussion: [Functional group tagging - revisited](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3915/functional-group-tagging-revisited) where it was decided that [aromatic-chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aromatic-chemistry) should be restricted to carbocyclic compounds.

Comment: Having done the edit, I think [aromatic-chemistry] is a more reasonable and official-looking name than [aromatic-compounds], but that's another matter.

Comment: I'm sorry, that was a typo. Thanks for correcting it.

Comment: I think it should be [heterocyclic-compounds]. Otherwise it would look like chemistry itself was heterocyclic ;)

Comment: Well you can have multiple tags so some would just have  [aromatic-compounds], some would have  [aromatic-compounds] + [heterocyclic-chemistry] and some just [heterocyclic-chemistry]

Comment: @Mithoron In some ways, that would be more closely aligned with our current tagging system, which has carbonyl-compounds, aromatic-compounds, ... I am glad I have only lumped the tag on two new questions so far! I think we can change it to that. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Does this mean we should also have [tag:anti-aromatic-compounds]? Doesn't seem like nearly as common a topic, though.

Comment: @hBy2Py No, antiaromaticity is bit controversial. All suspected compound can be tagged as hydrocarbons or heterocyclic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have been adding this tag to a few questions every day, starting with the obvious aromatic candidates. My search query has been `<heterocycle> -[heterocyclic-compounds] is:question`.

- **Done**: furan, pyrrole, pyridine, thiophene, indole, oxazole, thiazole, isoxazole
- **In progress**: [imidazole](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/search?q=imidazole+is%3Aquestion+-%5Bheterocyclic-compounds%5D)

Some other keywords to search for:

- (aromatic 6-membered) pyridazine, pyrimidine, pyrazine;
- (aromatic fused) benzofuran, benzothiophene, isobenzofuran, isoindole, quinoline, isoquinoline, benzopyrylium, purine
- (oxidised) pyrone, pyranone, pyridone, benzopyrone, pyrrolidone, furanone
- (saturated) pyrrolidine, piperidine, pyran, dihydrofuran, tetrahydrofuran (might be questionable), aziridine, lactam

That certainly seems like a lot and I doubt it's exhaustive just because there are so many combinations in which we can arrange atoms nowadays. However, I presume the number will get less and less as I move on to the more exotic heterocycles.

Answer (score 5):

There doesn’t seem to be any need for discussion. Vote up this answer if you approve what Orthocresol suggested, namely:

- [heterocyclic-compounds](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heterocyclic-compounds) should be the tag name
- heterocyclic aromatic compounds should also be tagged [aromatic-compounds](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aromatic-compounds) because they are aromatic
- [heterocyclic-compounds](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heterocyclic-compounds) would also include e.g. piperidine.