# Organic oxidation and reductions tag

Tags: discussion, tags

I cannot find an earlier discussion pertaining to this tag, so I'll post this today. I've noticed the [organic-reduction](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/organic-reduction) for a fair amount of time now. It has 14 questions tagged as of today. However, I cannot find the pertinent meta post about its creation.

[This](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3915/tag-review-2017-i-functional-group-tagging-revisited) is the only meta post relevant to its creation. However, notice that it documents both [organic-reduction](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/organic-reduction) and [organic-oxidation](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/organic-oxidation) should be created.

So:

1. Why was [organic-oxidation](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/organic-oxidation) never created?
2. Why was it thought better to *not* have a unified tag, like [organic-redox](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/organic-redox), similar to the general [redox](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/redox) tag we already have?

With reference to the second point, the [tagging Google document](https://docs.google.com/document/d/12ZhOeMCf_3LwvavAxiJBwx9QEPuHlGR2971vr5KIOjY/edit), mentions usage of "organic-redox", so I believe there *was* some deliberation about its creation, but it never got through.

Comment: Why was a tag never created? Duh, because no one created the tag.  And why no unified tags? Ask ortho. He's too weird for anyone to understand.

Comment: @M.A.R. "because no one created the tag." I think the same too. I only restrained myself from creating that tag because there wasn't much clarity on the unified tag instead (i like the unified tag more btw).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1. Why was organic-oxidation never created?

Because essentially we were too busy doing other things and also did not want to spam the front page with old questions.
We decided it'll be best to roll out these tags initially on new questions, and add it to older questions whenever they come up. We do most processes this way, the slow way, to avoid excessive turnover on the front page and get everyone to adjust slowly.

> 2. Why was it thought better to not have a unified tag, like organic-redox, similar to the general redox tag we already have?

Essentially for the same reason why we do not any longer want to use redox for these types of reactions. While every reduction needs an oxidation for balance, in most organic syntheses the focus lies on the substrates, products, and mechanisms involved. These differ significantly. It doesn't make much sense lumping the reduction of an alkene into the same category as the oxidation of an alcohol.

Comment: Oh, ok. So, if I create and start using [organic-oxidation] on the new questions that are posted, is it ok? (not on the old ones unless there is a TRE) And, "why we do not any longer want to use redox for these types of reactions." [tag:redox] is to be used for general _inorganic_ reactions, right? (the tag wiki does not clarify this ambiguity)

Comment: Yes, you can start using it on new questions. Redox should be used in the cases where both, the reduction and oxidation, are important; that is not limited to inorganic chemistry, but it will most likely be the more often used there.

Comment: Ok. Can you please clarify that part about redox in its tag wiki? https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tags/redox/info It currently has no proper tag usage defined...

Comment: @GaurangTandon Still not back, doing a drive-by only, sorry. I'm sure you can come up with something that gets approved...

Comment: Oh, I thought you were back (when will you be back, anyway? it's been too long already :( ) Anyway, I'll try editing it out. On my way to Research Assistant ^_^